# In Chef how to Create a template in append mode

Tags: templates, resources, chef-infra

```
template "/etc/myfile.log" do
  source "myfile.log"
  owner root
  group root
  mode 644
end
```

My Question is how can i create above file in append mode, next time this above resource run it should not override the content, but it should append it.

Comment: You can't. What is the problem you trying to solve?

Comment: @DracoAter I am installing oracle database, i need my listener file to be appended, so that i can install different versions of oracle database on same vm

Comment: In this case you should have a look at the [partial template](https://docs.chef.io/resource_template.html#partial-templates), one 'master' template with a loop inside including partial for each database (with correct option according to the loop). I didn't used it myself but can write an answer if really needed

Comment: @Tensibai Please do it, it would be a great help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I'll do something 'simple' for the idea, a real oracle conf is too long for here.

Using attributes to define the DB (you may use a databag too)

Attribute.rb

```
default['databases']['first']['codepage'] = "utf8"
default['databases']['first']['basedir'] = "/var/data/db1"
default['databases']['second']['codepage'] = "utf8"
default['databases']['second']['basedir'] = "/var/data/db2"
```

DB.erb

```
#Section <%= @dbname %>
  <%= @dbname %>.codepage = "<%= @props['codepage'] %>"
  <%= @dbname %>.path     = "<%= @props['basedir'] %>"
#End of section for <%= @dbname %>
```

Master.erb

```
#Any configuration needing to be there as common
default.codepage = "cp1252"
default.path     = "/var/data/default"

<%- node['databases'].each do |db,properties|
  <%= render "DB.erb", :variables => {:dbname => db, :props => properties } %>

<%- end.unless node['databases'].nil? %>
```

Here the master template will iterate over an attribute to render the DB.erb template inside itself with the properties passed.

The resulting file would be:

```
default.codepage = "cp1252"
default.path     = "/var/data/default"

#Section first
  first.codepage = "utf8"
  first.path     = "/var/data/db2"
#End of section for first

#Section second
  second.codepage = "utf8"
  second.path     = "/var/data/db2"
#End of section for second
```

Hope it gives enought indication to use in your particular case